# Regular expression to Match addresses

Tags: c#, regex

I have below set of strings to be searched :

> 1Dept Neurosci, The Univ. of New Mexico, ALBUQUERQUE, NM; 2Mol. and
>   Human Genet.,  Baylor Col. of Med., Houston,, TX; 3Psychiatry, Univ.
>   of Texas Southwestern Med. Ctr., Dallas,  TX; 4Clin. Genet., Erasmus
>   Univ. Med. Ctr., Rotterdam, Netherlands; 5Human Genet., Emory  Univ.,
>   Atlanta, GA

Above is a set of addresses , which starts with a digit (used to link it to the person).Need to search all the address as :

> 1Dept Neurosci, The Univ. of New Mexico, ALBUQUERQUE, NM 
>  2Mol.
>   and Human Genet.,  Baylor Col. of Med., Houston,, TX 
>  3Psychiatry,
>   Univ. of Texas Southwestern Med. Ctr., Dallas,  TX
>  4Clin. Genet.,
>   ErasmusUniv. Med. Ctr., Rotterdam, Netherlands
>  5Human Genet.,
>   Emory  Univ.Atlanta, GA

I have written the below Regex :

```
\d\w+,*
```

It only matches a digit followed by a word . How can I modify it .Please suggest is there any better way.

How can I do the same thing with (Digit in the last ):

> *X. ZHAO1, W. GUO1, A. M. ALLAN1, R. ZONG2, L. ZHANG1, E. B. JOHNSON1,  E. G. SCHALLER1, A. C. MURTHY1, S. L. GOGGIN1,2, A. EISCH3,4, B. A.
>   OOSTRA4,5, D. L.  NELSON2,3, P. JIN5;

Comment: You should better specify the input requirements. Are all addresses separated by semicolon? If so, can any address contain a semicolon? And so on.

Comment: No not necessarily semicolon.Need to search till next degit.

Comment: @Burfi digit in the last..cant understand u..give us some valid examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search seems complicated. What I understood from the above understanding that the string will be searched and the result will be returned

I am doing it based on the following string

> 1Dept Neurosci, The Univ. of New Mexico, ALBUQUERQUE, NM

Here is the code snippet.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string txt="1Dept Neurosci, The Univ. of New Mexico, ALBUQUERQUE, NM ";

      string re1="(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 1
      string re2="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";   // Word 1
      string re3=".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
      string re4="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";   // Word 2
      string re5="(,)"; // Any Single Character 1
      string re6="(.*?),";  // Command Seperated Values 1

      Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
      Match m = r.Match(txt);
      if (m.Success)
      {
            String int1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
            String word1=m.Groups[2].ToString();
            String word2=m.Groups[3].ToString();
            String c1=m.Groups[4].ToString();
            String csv1=m.Groups[5].ToString();
            Console.Write("("+int1.ToString()+")"+"("+word1.ToString()+")"+"("+word2.ToString()+")"+"("+c1.ToString()+")"+"("+csv1.ToString()+")"+"\n");
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

One more thing. If you need to generate regex and search for it you might want to check out [this](http://txt2re.com/index-csharp.php3)

Please let me know if this helps.

**EDIT**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string txt="X. ZHAO1,";

      string re1="((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))";   // Variable Name 1
      string re2="(\\.)";   // Any Single Character 1
      string re3="(\\s+)";  // White Space 1
      string re4="((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))";   // Variable Name 2
      string re5="(,)"; // Any Single Character 2

      Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
      Match m = r.Match(txt);
      if (m.Success)
      {
            String var1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
            String c1=m.Groups[2].ToString();
            String ws1=m.Groups[3].ToString();
            String var2=m.Groups[4].ToString();
            String c2=m.Groups[5].ToString();
            Console.Write("("+var1.ToString()+")"+"("+c1.ToString()+")"+"("+ws1.ToString()+")"+"("+var2.ToString()+")"+"("+c2.ToString()+")"+"\n");
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the updated part , its working well , how can I exclude trailing (,) from the results.

Comment: if you want to exclude the trailing , then remove the "string re5="(,)";" and the corresponding usages of re5. Hope this helps... :)

Answer (score 3):

a simple `regex` as you need (starts with a digit):

```
\d+[^\d]+
```

explain:

```
\d+                      digits (0-9) 
                         (1 or more times, matching the most amount possible)

[^\d]+                   any character except: digits (0-9) 
                         (1 or more times, matching the most amount possible)
```

and a sample code:

```
var strInput = "1Dept Neurosci, The Univ. of New Mexico, ALBUQUERQUE, NM; 2Mol. and Human Genet., Baylor Col. of Med., Houston,, TX; 3Psychiatry, Univ. of Texas Southwestern Med. Ctr., Dallas, TX; 4Clin. Genet., Erasmus Univ. Med. Ctr., Rotterdam, Netherlands; 5Human Genet., Emory Univ., Atlanta, GA";

var adresses = new List<string>();

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(strInput, @"\d+[^\d]+"))
{
    adresses.Add(match.Value);
}
```